# Setting date and time format for Bootstrap date time picker

Tags: datetimepicker, datetime-format, bootstrap-datetimepicker

Im using bootstrap datetime picker [Bootstarp picker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#format)

how can i change default date and time format.

I have tried dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii',dateFormat: 'yymmdd' in

```js
 $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
 dateFormat: 'yymmdd',
 timeFormat: 'hhmm'
 });
```

But none of them seem to work.
Please help i want change the dateFormat to yy-mm-dd and time format to HH:mm:ss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set the `format` option with a valid [moment format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

```
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` did not work for me.

The following did though:

```
$( function() {$( "#datetimepicker" ).datetimepicker({ format: "d-m-y H:i" });} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below

```
 $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
 format: 'yyyy-dd-mm',
 });
```